# Can the relocation of one control point of a NURBS curve be compensated by an adjustment of some weights?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, curves, polygons, spline

Can the relocation of one control point of a NURBS curve be compensated
by an adjustment of some weights? How to show that there exists NURBS curves for which even the
modification of all weights does not suffice to compensate the relocation of one control point.